# How to remove port number from an IP address string

Tags: c#, .net, string, listbox

I am trying to separate the IP address from the port in a list box. But my code creates a string that contains both the port number and ":". How can ignore the ":" and keep only the IP?

IPs look like this:

```
192.168.0.12:80
192.168.0.2:123
192.168.0.3:1337
```

Here is my current code:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string item = lb.Items[i] as string;
    item = item.Substring(item.LastIndexOf(":"));
    lb.Items[i] = item;
}
```

Comment: `item = item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(':'));`

Comment: item = item.Split(':')[0];

Answer (score 8):

You could parse it into a Uri and then inspect the `Host` value:

```
String ip = "192.168.0.3:1337";
Uri uri = new Uri("http://" + ip);
MessageBox.Show(uri.Port.ToString()); //shows 1337
MessageBox.Show(uri.Host.ToString()); //shows 192.168.0.3
```

This has the added benefit of making sure the URI is valid and will work for addresses that do not contain a `:` whereas using `IndexOf(':')` will not, so you would have to do an additional check to see if the string `.Contains` it first

Answer (score 8):

You could split the string:

```
string ip = item.Split(":")[0]
```

or you could create an Uri object and extract from it the Host value

Comment: This would behave very badly with an IPv6 address.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's true, but OP asked with 3  IPv4 examples

Comment: _nod_, but answers are for everyone who sees the question in the future, not just the OP. I suppose one could edit the question title to specify IPv4 to keep folks for whom the answer is out-of-scope out.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old question. Just posting a solution because even today I faced this issue.

```
 private string GetIPAddress()
    {
      string ipaddress = string.Empty;
      if (HttpContext.Current != null)
      {
        ipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipaddress))
          ipaddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      }

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipaddress))
      {
        var splitList = ipaddress.Split(':');
        //For IPv6 - Format >> [1fff:0:a88:85a3::ac1f]:8001  - This will parse the value to get proper IP from IPv6 format.
        if (splitList.Length > 2)
        {
          ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress).ToString();
        }
        // For IPv4 - Format >> 192.168.0.3:1337  - This will only take value before : (colon)
        else if (splitList.Length == 2)
        {
          ipaddress = splitList[0];
        }

      }
      return ipaddress;
    }
```

Hope this may help someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to remove port number from IP address like below

```
string input = "52.240.151.125:47042";
string pattern = ":\\d{1,5}";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You will get below output

[image: Regex output]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript way

```
const uri = "192.168.0.3:1337";
  
const url = new URL(uri);
console.log(url.port); //shows 1337
console.log(url.hostname); //shows 192.168.0.3
```

This Answer helped in thinking about this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38617619/revisions

Comment: This is a question tagged C#